# Скрипт открытия и закрытия формы поиска

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Мне нужно написать скрипт, при котором, при нажатии картинки "search"

```html
<div class="search"><img src="Images/search.svg" onclick="disp()"></div>
```

откроется форма поиска:

```html
<div id="searchForm" >
            <div class="box">
                <input type="search" id="search"/>
                <span id="closeSearch"><img src="Images/closeSearch.svg" onclick="close()"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

С этим я успешно справился. Нашел скрипт в интернете:

```js
function disp() {
                    let form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
                    form.style.display = "block";
                    
                }
```

При этом, мне нужно реализовать закрытие этой формы поиска на картинку "closeSearch" (она появится вместе с формой поиска). Подсмотрев на функцию открытия, я решил таким же методом сделать и закрытие формы:

```html
function close() {
                    let close = document.getElementById("searchForm");
                    close.style.display = "none";
                }
```

Но что-то пошло не так, и оно не работает. Буду весьма благодарен за вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function disp() {
                    let form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
                    form.style.display = "block";
                    
                }
                
                function closet() {
                    let close = document.getElementById("searchForm");
                    close.style.display = "none";
                }
```

```css
#searchForm {
display: none
}
img {
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="search">Нажми--> <img src="Images/search.svg" onclick="disp()"></div>

<div id="searchForm" >
            <div class="box">
                <input type="search" id="search"/>
                <span id="closeSearch">Нажми--> <img src="Images/closeSearch.svg" onclick="closet()"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Странно, можно объяснение как так? у меня #searchForm { display: none } и до этого стоял. Все что изменилось, это добавление надписи "Нажми" и изменение названия функции из close на closet. При этом, всё работает. Как так?

Comment: Всегда стараюсь не давать одинаковых имен функциям и переменным + не давать имен, которые могут быть зарезервированы языком (а close уж очень вероятно)